# How to create a tree view expanded to repeated items in Apache POI

Tags: excel, java-8, apache-poi

I have a requirement to transform an Excel from:

```
A -> B -> C -> 10 
A -> B -> C -> 15 
A -> B -> C -> 20 
D -> E -> F -> 10 
D -> E -> F -> 15 
D -> E -> F -> 20
```

To:

```
A ->  
     B -> 
         C -> 10 
         C -> 15 
         C -> 20 
D -> 
     E -> 
         F -> 10
         F -> 15
         F -> 20
```

Is there any POI method to facilitate to achieve this result? I'm already reading the excel file
and generating the a result excel, but I couldn't achieve this logic :(.

Comment: For me it is not clear how this showed content would look like in a `Excel` sheet, neither the first  nor the second. Please clarify.

Comment: @AxelRichter i posted the answer. If you have any doubt, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically transform each cell in one column keeping the last value unchangeable:

[image]

To:

[image]

I could achieve \o/ by this code:

```
for (int sheetnum = START_SHEET; sheetnum < numSheets; sheetnum++) {
                XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum);

                // Total Rows
                int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                // Variable to check the names
                List<XSSFCell> checkDimCellsName = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = START_ROW_CONTENT; i < rows; i++) {
                    List<XSSFCell> cellsName = new ArrayList<>();
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow((short) i);

                    for (int j = START_CELL_CONTENT; j < colsBefore + 1; ++j) {
                        // Cell content
                        cellsName.add(row.getCell((short) j));
                        row.removeCell(row.getCell((short) j));
                    }

                    // Space to concat cells
                    String space = "";
                    if (checkDimCellsName.isEmpty()) {
                        for (XSSFCell cellName : cellsName) {
                            String newDimNameCellValue = space + cellName.getStringCellValue();
                            cellName.setCellValue(newDimNameCellValue);
                            checkDimCellsName.add(cellName);
                            space += "  ";
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (int c = 0; c < cellsName.size(); c++) {
                            if (checkDimCellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue().trim()
                                    .equals(cellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue().trim()) && c < cellsName.size() - 1) {
                                cellsName.get(c).setCellValue("");
                            } else {
                                checkDimCellsName.get(c).setCellValue(cellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue());
                                cellsName.get(c).setCellValue(space + cellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            space += "  ";
                        }
                    }

                    int rowsCreated = 0;
                    Collections.reverse(cellsName);
                    for (int c = 0; c < cellsName.size(); c++) {
                        if (cellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue().trim().length() > 0) {
                            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) START_CELL_CONTENT);
                            cell.setCellValue(cellsName.get(c).getStringCellValue());
                            cell.setCellStyle(cellsName.get(c).getCellStyle());

                            if (c == cellsName.size() - 1) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                if (cellsName.get(c + 1).getStringCellValue().trim().length() > 0) {
                                    sheet.shiftRows(i, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
                                    row = sheet.createRow(i);
                                    rowsCreated++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    i += rowsCreated;
                    rows += rowsCreated;
                }
            }
```